# How to delete a range of rows from Cassandra using c#

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am trying to get this program to run. The database is created, and there are values in it. Column "ts" of type BigInt is the primary key. When I try to execute

```
session.Execute(deleteAll);
```

it throws an exception. What is the correct way to delete all rows in Cassandra from c# where a key is between value1 and value2?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cassandra;
using Cassandra.Data;

namespace CasandraGettingStarted
{
    class Program
    {
        static long ninetySeventyTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;
        static string symbol = "SPX";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartCassandra();
        }

        protected static long ToUnixTimestampMicro(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return (dateTime.Ticks - ninetySeventyTicks) / 10;
        }

        static DateTime ConvertFromUnixTimestampMicro(double timestamp)
        {
            return new DateTime((long)timestamp * 10).AddYears(1969);//.ToLocalTime();
        }

        static void StartCassandra()
        {
            try
            {
                System.Random random = new Random(123456);

                Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1").Build();
                ISession session = cluster.Connect("timeseries");

                double minPrice = 1100.00;
                double maxPrice = 1200.00;

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    //long timestamp = (DateTime.Now.Ticks - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks) / 10;
                    System.DateTime nowMicro = System.DateTime.Now;
                    long timestamp = ToUnixTimestampMicro(nowMicro);
                    System.DateTime nowMicro1 = ConvertFromUnixTimestampMicro(timestamp);

                    Console.WriteLine(nowMicro.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));
                    Console.WriteLine(nowMicro1.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));

                    double bidD = random.NextDouble();
                    bidD = bidD * (maxPrice - minPrice) + minPrice;
                    double askD = bidD + random.NextDouble();

                    decimal bid = (decimal)bidD;
                    decimal ask = (decimal)askD;

                    bid = decimal.Round(bid, 2);
                    ask = decimal.Round(ask, 2);

                    Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} {1} {2} {3}", timestamp, symbol, bid, ask);

                    var batchStmt = new BatchStatement();
                    var v2Insert = new SimpleStatement("insert into underlying_data " +
                        "(ts, symbol, bid, ask) values(?, ?, ?, ?);");
                    batchStmt.Add(v2Insert.Bind(timestamp, symbol, bid, ask));

                    session.Execute(batchStmt);
                    // Insert Data
                    //session.Execute("insert into underlying_data (ts, symbol, bid, ask) values (timestamp, 'SPX', bid, ask)");

                    //Thread.Sleep(1);
                }

                RowSet result = session.Execute("select * from underlying_data");

                foreach (Row row in result)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", row["ts"], row["symbol"], row["bid"], row["ask"]);


                string deleteAll = @"select * from underlying_data where ts > ";
                deleteAll += ninetySeventyTicks.ToString();

                session.Execute(deleteAll);

                RowSet rows = session.Execute("select * from underlying_data");

                foreach (Row row in result)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", row["ts"], row["symbol"], row["bid"], row["ask"]);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

            // Wait for enter key before exiting
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session.Execute(deleteAll);
```

First of all, it looks like `deleteAll` is defined as a `SELECT` query:

```
string deleteAll = @"select * from underlying_data where ts > ";
    deleteAll += ninetySeventyTicks.ToString();
```

So that's not going to delete anything.  In fact, Cassandra only allows the `=` and `IN` operators on a primary key `SELECT`.  Although you didn't explicitly mention it, I'm sure the exception you saw was something like:

> [Invalid query] message="Only EQ and IN relation are supported on the partition key (unless you use the token() function)"

As the exception indicates, you can't use `>` or `<`, unless you encapsulate the values with the `token()` function.  But `token()` won't give you want you want, because primary key tokens are not ordered.

Likewise, if you attempt an actual `DELETE` with anything other than `=`, you'll get this:

> [Invalid query] message="Invalid operator < for PRIMARY KEY part id"

And unlike `SELECT`, a `DELETE` won't allow you do use greater/less than operators with the `token()` function.  The only alternative to deleting with the `=` operator and a primary key, is to give `DELETE` an `IN` clause of multiple primary keys.

You should also be aware that deleting data on a regular basis will produce a lot of tombstones, so delete-heavy usage patterns are generally discouraged with Cassandra.  For more information, check the documentation on the [CQL DELETE command](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/delete_r.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. So instead of delete, how do I search for all the rows > than and < than a given range?

Comment: @Ivan It's difficult to say without seeing your schema.  But you should probably create an additional table specifically designed for this query.  That table should have something else designated as its partitioning key, so that you can query by that and use `ts` as a clustering key.  Post your current table structure, and I'll make a recommendation.